# How to obtain only 5 rows for each value in the IN statement of the query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I some times have a situation, where I end up with huge chucks of data,I need go all the way down in the table to search for the values I have given  in the In statement, it would be easier for me If I can limit the values by 5-10 in the in statement

I some times use a combination of UNION and ROWNUM which has little help to do

Is there any way in oracle to sort the data ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us an example query? And what do you mean with an IN statement?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col order by in_value) as seqnum
      from t
      where col in ( . . . )
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```